# Hello I am not able to create account from google ads API

Tags: google-ads-api, google-contacts-api

The response I get from the API when trying to create a new account is: "customer is not allowed listed for accessing this feature.".
The function I am using is createCustomerClient.
and the account that I use for this action is my manager account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google ads sandbox for testing purpose then you must have to add your account as test user.
go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent 
click on add user 
add the email account in which your manager account exist.

Comment: This is a prod account and I am using the manager already